# How to insert data into database using a custom php MVC with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to store data into database.

I tried this:

In the **View** I created this form:

```
<form id="addControl" action="<?php echo URL ?>controles/addControl" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <input type="text" name="text2">
    <input type="text" name="text3">
    <input type="submit" name="Add">
</form>
```

Then I created a **Model**

**controles_model.php**

```
public function addControl(){
    $text1  = $_POST['text1'];
    $text2  = $_POST['text2'];              
    $text3  = $_POST['text3'];

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `controles` (field1, field2, field3 ) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($text1,$text2,$text3));

    if($stmt == true){
        return "good";
    }else{
        return "wrong";
    }
}
```

Then I created a **Controller**:

**controles.php**

```
class Controles extends Controller {    
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index(){        
        $this->view->render('controles/index');
    }
    function addControl(){
        $this->model->addControl();
    }
}
```

and finally, for the **JS** file I created this:

```
$("#addControl").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var url     = $(this).attr('action');
    var data    = $(this).serialize();

    $.post(url, data, function(response) {
        if(response == "good"){
            $("#insertedSuccessfully").show();
        }else if(response == "wrong"){
            $("#notInserted").show();
        }   
    });
});
```

All this doesn't work. How can I fix it?

> NB: the database connection is OK, it work fine sine I can retreive
>   data from database.

Answer (score 1):

You have attached the event listener to the id `addControl` but your form is having the id `addData`. Therefore the var url might be `undefined` in your javascript code.

and in your php file use `$_POST` instead of `$POST`.

Also I would recommend to check your console for any javascript errors

Comment: Sorry, Its just an error, it's id="addControl" NOT id="addData"

Comment: $_POST its not $POST, Its just a typo here

Answer (score 0):

$POST is not the array given by PHP, but is like more $_POST.
So, in your model, you have no data to insert.

Comment: $_POST its not $POST, Its just a typo here. I edited the code above